Unity Can a variable, changing array be assigned for one spot in an array
So I might already have an answer for this but if I have a 2d array is there anyway to have a spot be in array that can change sizes and content?
If not, how could I go about this?  Can lists do this? If so how.  (I'm not great with lists.
Example:
int [] changingArray;

int [][] test = new int[][]{
new int[]{0,1,2,3,changingArray,5,6,7},
new int[]{0,1,2,3,changingArray,5,6,7}

}

and then later assign changingArray to different array size and content depending on input
the goal is to have something read the array 1,2,3,etc,,, plus the changingArray as well

OK, so while your second array can be a variable length, the question seems more what exactly are you trying to achieve with the array?

So I'm in too deep to change the entire system but basically I have a dialogue system where what people say changes based on your choices and while I have strings arrays assigned for the dialogue I have their portraits assigned to different int.  When execute above code it says I can't convert from type int to type int[], but even if I found out how to fix that, I want to know if it wouldn't work anyway.  I need the changing array for both the string array and int array to basically add the changed dialogue inside the array alongside the dialogue that doesn't change.

well firstly like the square brackets suggest while an array of int (eg int[]) is not a single int, therefore no a bunch cant be converted to a single.. you can pick 1 out by using its position such as test[0][0]

still not really clear to me what your exact use case for this is .. why not just have a list then and insert the other values in the middle?
